# How do I set table style with Office.js for Excel on Mac?

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to do something like

```
var tableOptions = {style: "TableStyleLight18"}; 

binding.setTableOptionsAsync(tableOptions, function(asyncResult){});
```

but I keep getting the following error

```
One or more of the tableOptions parameters have values that 
aren't allowed. Double-check the values and try again.
```

If I use `setSelectedDataAsync` with the same `tableOptions`, my style is just ignored. Both work fine in Excel Online and Windows.

Am I missing something? How do I format a table in Mac for Excel using Office.js?

Answer (score 1):

The style value `TableStyleLight18` looks valid.
You can try [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/table.md) API.

```
try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let table = context.workbook.tables.getItem('Tabl2')
    table.style = 'TableStyleLight18'
    await context.sync();
    });
}
catch (error) {
    //handle error
}
```

Constant value that represents the Table style. Possible values are: `TableStyleLight1` thru `TableStyleLight21`, `TableStyleMedium1` thru `TableStyleMedium28`, `TableStyleDark1` thru `TableStyleDark11`. A custom user-defined style present in the workbook can also be specified (no API to create custom style yet).